# I want to create a script score in Elasticsearch upon index A using count aggregation coming from index B , is that possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES version 7 having 2 indices

- Purchase index : With fields of (User - Purchased product - Purchase time)
- User index : having filed representing properties of a user.

I want to build a function score script based upon user index using this formula

```
"script" : {
    "source" : "decayNumericExp(params.origin, params.scale, params.offset, params.decay, Purchased products in the last month)",
    "params": { 
        "origin": 0,
        "scale":1,
        "decay" : 0.6,
        "offset" : 0
    }
}
```

But Purchased products in the last month can only be retrieved using count aggregations from Purchase index , how can i include it in the script score in query time using the query built upon user index ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access fields from different indices at query time. The best way to go would be to enrich the `users` index w/ the purchase data and update it on-demand -- as soon as a user purchases something.